# change oracleDataSource to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql

I have this function

```
public OracleDataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            dataSource.setURL(url);
            dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
            dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I need to change to swap from oracle to postresql db,there is some equivalent from OracleDataSource to use it with Postrgesql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource` and `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`.

See [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-ds.html) for details.